# How do I remaster a Ubuntu cd into a Ubuntu cd with only Gnome Shell?

Tags: gnome, customization, remastersys

I was wondering if this was possible and easy to do.

I want to take my Ubuntu 11.10 64bit Cd and remaster it so that it will instead be a Gnome3 live Cd that I can install later install Gnome Shell with it instead of Unity.

I know that Fedora already comes this way but I don't like the rpm package format and love the deb package format along with ppa's.

I would also like to change some of the default programs on the cd as well as add other repositories other than the normal default ones.

Also I would like to include all updates to the files that came with then Cd when I was originally made to make it as up to date as possible.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: There are already Ubuntu spin-offs that come with Gnome Shell (Because that it's name Gnome Shell, as Ubuntu *COMES* with Gnome 3).

Comment: Ok, that was what I was going for. A way to have it be just Gnome Shell and Gnome 3 and no Unity and Unity 2d.

Comment: Does any of the Ubuntu spin-offs you pointed out use the debian package management system as well?

Comment: I did look at the page you suggested and didn't see a way to include ppa's. Also I think what you are suggesting is maybe to strip out Unity, Ubuntu, and Unity 2D and the just use remaster to make a new iso of that system with just gnome shell and gnome 3. If so what packages would I remove? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do what ever you want to do then after doing all the desired changes.Install remastersys
and view this [tutorial](http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/06/how-to-remaster-ubuntu-to-get-a-customised-distribution/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.